# iis7 doesn't support multiple applications

Tags: url, redirect, iis-7, configuration, ip

i am running iis7.  the web site has 2 unique applications each in its own folder structure and each installed as an application in iis.

the server has 2 ip addresses associated with it.  in iis6 on the application property page all you had to do was specify an ip address and that address would automatically route you to the associated application.

this feature has either been removed or well hidden in iis7.  so the question i have is, how do you associate a specific ip address with a specific iis application in iis7.

urlrewrite doesn't seem to cover this case but then again its 3 in the morning...

we are associated ip addresses with specific applications because long term the transaction volume associated with each application will dictate using its own server.
\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open iis7  **-->>**    Right Click `Site`  **-->>**   select  `Add Website` **-->>**

here you can set `ip address,port,physical path` of your app(ie in wwwroot) and `hostname`.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: iis7 only lets you set alias, application pool, and physical path.  how do you get to ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the web app and go to Edit Bindings.. you set the IP and/or hostname bindings there, they've also moved binding a certificate to an IP there too

edit after discussion:

If you need to bind applications to different IPs and/or hostnames then you need to set them up as seperate website applications.  This can be done by right-clicking `Sites` and selecting `Add Website`

You can remove or stop the Default Website Application once you've configured your applications.

For further information, the reason you can add application within a Website is so that you can have say, a blog in a subdirectory eg `www.somewebsite.com/blog` where the main website is one app and the blog is another.  Could even be a wordpress where the main website is asp.net

Comment: the only place i see bindings is at the web site level, not the application level.  i can associated a domain name with an internal ip but that doesn't seem to provide any benefit that i don't get with dns.

Comment: Yeah, if you need separate bindings then run your two apps as two web apps

Comment: thats what i am trying to do.  i want app a to be associated with ip 1 and app b to be associated with ip 2.  what i can't figure out is how to associate ip1 so that `https://ip1/` takes me to the root of the application and not the root of the web server.

Comment: you need to add a new website and make the association.. sounds like you're adding applications to one website, but because you want separate bindings, you need separate websites. So like satinder suggests, right click on Site and go to 'Add Website' it is on mine and add both of your apps this way.  Then you could just remove or stop the default website application

Comment: I've edit the main answer with new info, with a further info on adding apps within a website